# How to use complex number method to prove

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

that a quadrilateral whose two pairs of opposite sides are equal in length is a parallelogram. Please do not use any axioms of synthetic geometry but can use vector geometry.

Suppose four distinct complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, $z_3$, such that $|z_2-z_1|= |z_4-z_3|$ and $|z_3-z_2|= |z_1-z_4|$, prove that $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4$.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: I tried hard but failed to conclude that z1+z3=z2+z4.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant.  Please show us what you did.  How did you represent the fact that opposite side have equal length?  What statement (in terms of the vectors) do you think it's necessary to prove?  How did you try to prove it?  Where did you get stuck?  If you do that, someone will be able to tell what, if anything, you did wrong, or to point out the insight you're missing.  Otherwise, you're just asking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: @tmpbin "a quadrilateral whose two pairs of opposite sides are equal in length" is a *definition* of a parallelogram. With or without complex numbers.  It is not clear to me what you want to prove?

Comment: @user376343 This is not the ordinary definition of a parallelogram but a theorem. Now I have realized my mistake.